# Laravel conditional Query not working

Tags: mysql, laravel

Laravel conditional query does not return results as expected i am adding a **whereIn** Clause if  condition is true. if i remove if statement then its return results as expected but not work when this conditional clause is added to query

This is my code:

```
$cf = $request->session()->get('filter');


    $designs = DB::table('designs');
    $count   = DB::table('designs');

    $appFilters = $request->session()->get('filter');


    if($request->session()->has('filter')){ 

        $stringFilter = $this->filterIntToString($appFilters);

        $fid =  array_unique($this->fillterSearchEngine($appFilters));

        $designs->whereIn('fid', $fid);
        $count->whereIn('fid', $fid);


    }

    $stringFilter = [];

    $sizeFilters = $request->session()->get('filSize');
    $nsf = [];
    foreach ($sizeFilters as $str) {
        $str = str_replace('-', ',', $str);
        array_push($nsf, $str);
    }



    $designs->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    $designs->whereIn('o_size', $nsf);
    $designs->where('cat', $c);
    $designs->where('sub', $s);
    $designs->take(16);

    $results = $designs->get();
    $count->whereIn('o_size', $sizeFilters)->where('cat', $c)->where('sub', $s);
    $counts = $designs->count();
    $html = view('app-pages.designs-filter-ajax')->with('stringFilter', $stringFilter)->with('appFilter', $appFilters)->with('designs', $results)->render();

    return ['success', $html, $counts, count($results)];
```

**This is Query Log**

```
[{"query":"select * from `designs` where `fid` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `o_size` in (?) and `cat` = ? and `sub` = ? order by `created_at` desc limit 16","bindings":[21,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,666,667,668,669,670,671,672,673,674,675,676,677,678,679,680,681,682,683,684,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946,947,948,949,950,1198,1199,1200,1201,1202,1203,1204,1205,1206,1207,1208,1209,1210,1211,1212,1213,1214,1215,1216,1464,1465,1466,1467,1468,1469,1470,1471,1472,1473,1474,1475,1476,1477,1478,1479,1480,1481,1482,1730,1731,1732,1733,1734,1735,1736,1737,1738,1739,1740,1741,1742,1743,1744,1745,1746,1747,1748,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268,2269,2270,2271,2272,2273,2274,2275,2276,2277,2278,2279,2280,2528,2529,2530,2531,2532,2533,2534,2535,2536,2537,2538,2539,2540,2541,2542,2543,2544,2545,2546,2794,2795,2796,2797,2798,2799,2800,2801,2802,2803,2804,2805,2806,2807,2808,2809,2810,2811,2812,3060,3061,3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,3067,3068,3069,3070,3071,3072,3073,3074,3075,3076,3077,3078,3326,3327,3328,3329,3330,3331,3332,3333,3334,3335,3336,3337,3338,3339,3340,3341,3342,3343,3344,"50,30,mm","business cards","classic"],"time":13},{"query":"select count(*) as aggregate from `designs` where `fid` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `o_size` in (?) and `cat` = ? and `sub` = ? limit 16","bindings":[21,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,666,667,668,669,670,671,672,673,674,675,676,677,678,679,680,681,682,683,684,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946,947,948,949,950,1198,1199,1200,1201,1202,1203,1204,1205,1206,1207,1208,1209,1210,1211,1212,1213,1214,1215,1216,1464,1465,1466,1467,1468,1469,1470,1471,1472,1473,1474,1475,1476,1477,1478,1479,1480,1481,1482,1730,1731,1732,1733,1734,1735,1736,1737,1738,1739,1740,1741,1742,1743,1744,1745,1746,1747,1748,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268,2269,2270,2271,2272,2273,2274,2275,2276,2277,2278,2279,2280,2528,2529,2530,2531,2532,2533,2534,2535,2536,2537,2538,2539,2540,2541,2542,2543,2544,2545,2546,2794,2795,2796,2797,2798,2799,2800,2801,2802,2803,2804,2805,2806,2807,2808,2809,2810,2811,2812,3060,3061,3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,3067,3068,3069,3070,3071,3072,3073,3074,3075,3076,3077,3078,3326,3327,3328,3329,3330,3331,3332,3333,3334,3335,3336,3337,3338,3339,3340,3341,3342,3343,3344,"50,30,mm","business cards","classic"],"time":1}]
```

Comment: Try to implement it like this in if statement $designs = $designs->whereIn('fid', $fid);

Comment: How you set `session()`,`'filter'` ?

Comment: Like this => $request->session()->push('filter', $fn);

Comment: there are two different kinds of filter

Comment: @aishazafar  i tried above code but still not working

Comment: Try to debug your query after enabling query log. Try to print your query after and before if statement. I hope you'll be able to find the issue in your query this way.

Comment: updated query log in question

Comment: Try to roun this sql command in your phpphpmyadmin or whatewer you use < cpp.sh/8ezej > and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

First check weather you are getting data in $appFilters using var_dump if not the error should be in getting the variable from the session

Comment: what is the output you are getting for $fid

Comment: an array of filter ids